# how can mybatis map all the properties, which is correspond to field in DB, in a certain Object?

Tags: mybatis

The logic is a little bit complicated, so i'll give an example here:
Imagine we have three fields in a table, namely A, B, C. the following xml mapper will fill in the property in an instance of Blog class:

```sql
<resultMap type="Blog"  id="result">
    <result property="A" column="A"/>
    <result property="B" column="B"/>
    <result property="C" column="C"/>
</resultMap>
```

The problem is that if I got a class User, which includes three properties, namely A, B and C. How can I use the former resultMap to fill in the A, B properties in a instance of class User. That means I wanna fill in all the properties which the above resultMap can map to. How to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that:

```xml
<select id="selectUsers" parameterType="int" resultType="com.someapp.model.User">
    select id             as A, 
           username       as B,   
           hashedPassword as D
    from some_table
    where id = #{id}
</select>
```

MyBatis automatically create a `ResultMap` to map the columns to the JavaBean properties based on name. If the column names did not match exactly, you could employ select clause aliases on the column names to make the labels match. A, B and C should provide getter and setters.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Vargas is correct. Of course you should provide the appropiate getters and setters. If you want to work with objects to do basic crud operations in each table you should check the [MyBatisGenerator](http://www.mybatis.org/generator/). This will give you a class per each table and generate the interfaces and xml implementations for basic operations including powerful conditional selects with the appropiate config. If you follow the tutorial you will only write like this:

```java
SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
try {
  UserMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
  List<User> allRecords = mapper.selectByExample(null);//Select All
} finally {
  sqlSession.close();
}
```

This can be further optimized (MyBatis plugins or integration with spring) but that would be the simple use after generating classes.